# Single executable binary of Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, compilation, executable, packaging

What options are available to create a single binary that contains my Ruby gem along with a Ruby runtime?

My goal is to be able to share the executable with another developer and they could simply run the executable from their command line passing it required arguments similar to Vagrant.

P.S. The program is intended to be run in a *nix operating systems with Ruby versions >= 2.5.

Comment: The typical way it to make a gem containing an [executable](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable). Your users can then install it via `gem install` and run your executable.

Comment: @anothermh the OP said _"to be run in a *nix operating systems with Ruby versions >= 2.5"_ so I assumed Ruby to be installed already.

Comment: @Stefan, @anothermh Thanks for the idea of `gem install`. But the gem I am writing is internal to my organization and we do not have our own RubyGems repository. I would not be able to publish it to public repository. I'd like to understand how they package Vagrant to be a single binary. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like my comment was removed for using the F word. I had essentially said it sounded like OP was asking for a single binary with both the runtime and the gem based on the words "a single binary that contains my Ruby gem along with a Ruby runtime". If OP could elaborate it would help, but if that's their goal then it's probably going to be a nightmare to do based on my past experience of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [ruby-packer](https://github.com/pmq20/ruby-packer) but the repo has been dead for a while. There are forks with Ruby 2.5. It can produce binaries for Linux, Mac, Windows and probably some others.

For linux based systems you could use [AppImage](https://appimage.org/) (there are some scripts found on google that put a ruby in the image) or maybe [Snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/#ruby).

When you have ruby-packer and the dependencies installed, it's just a matter of `rubyc -o binary-name gem-executable-name` in the app's directory. Takes about 15 minutes to compile.

Comment: Any idea what vagrant uses to create a single binary?

Comment: I think they have something that does something similar to ruby packer, the go source is here: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant-installers/blob/master/substrate/launcher/main.go

Comment: Sorry for hijacking this thread, but can tell me is I need 32 or 64 bit Ruby and MS VS versions? 
And if rubyc 0.4.0 support Ruby2.6?

Comment: @Vitaly the ruby-packer has been quite unmaintained for a while, i don't think there's a ruby 2.6 version. I think you can compile it on a 32bit windows and it should work.